# Why is multi-way ANOVA typically taught with reference to interaction terms, whereas multiple regression isn't?

Tags: regression, anova, multiple-regression, interaction, teaching

For instance, reference to an interaction term will almost always be made when Two-way ANOVA is taught. However, when considering a regression with two continuous predictors and one continuous outcome, I've found (psychology teaching context) that students are often surprised that it's possible for there to be an interaction term.

Comment: ANOVA is regression, mathematicall, so this has nothing to do with the methods, only with traditions of teaching.

Comment: While I accept that the division between ANOVA and Regression is just a historical accident, I wondered if in this case there might be some pedagogical or other reason for the teaching tradition I have been observed. That is, is there some difference between a regression with two categorical predictors and one with two continuous predictors that justifies a more explicit consideration of interactions?

Comment: One difference may be that ANOVA is often used in designed experiments, with (at least close to) orthogonal predictors, so interactions might be estimated in a stable way. with regression, more often used in observational studies, colinearity is more often an issue so that estimation of interaction may be unstable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few reasons for this.

First, in psychology departments, statistics course are, too often, taught be people who don't really have a background in statistics. And nearly always taught TO people who have little interest in statistics. I have a PhD in psychometrics and consulted for many years with psychologists (and other social and behavioral scientists) and can say that many of them only learned statistics to pass their comps, and then promptly forgot it.

Of course this isn't *always* the case, but it often is.

Second, I think it's partly that ANOVA always has categorical independent variables (regression only sometimes) and it is easier to conceptualize interactions among categorical variables than continuous ones.

Third, I think that ANOVA often has far fewer IVs than regression does. Just take the name "two way ANOVA".  A whole separate name for having *two* IVs! With two IVs, there's only one possible interaction. Regression often has far more and the possible interactions grow fast. I have often seen references to regressions with *hundreds* of IVs (or even more). With 100 IVs you have 4950 possible two way interactions.  I haven't ever seen an ANOVA with anything like that many variables. (They might be out there, but I haven't seen them).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the field. In econometrics, interaction terms are very often included as explanatory variables in regressions, and this is taught to students.